# Lusin's Theorem Infinite Measure Counterexample

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose I have the measurable space $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ where $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Lusin's theorem states that for any measurable function $f$, measure $\mu$ on the space, and $A\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mu(A) < \infty$, then for each $\varepsilon>0$,$\exists K \subseteq A$ which is compact and is such that $\mu(A-K)<\varepsilon$ and $f$ is continuous on $K$.

I'm looking for a counterexample which illustrates why we require $\mu(A)<\infty$. Preferably I'd like the measure used to be the Lebesgue measure but any example will do, I just want to understand why the finite measure of the Borel set is required.

Comment: Consider the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and the non-compact $A=\mathbb{R}$. Then the statement that $\mu(\mathbb{R}-K)<\epsilon$ makes no sense for any compact $K$.

Comment: For any infinite regular measure $\mu$ (such as Lebesgue's) if a set $A$ is measurable and $\mu(A)=\infty$, there is no compact set $K\subset A$ for which $\mu(A\setminus K)<\infty$. The point of Luzin's theorem is that a function is (Lebesgue)-measurable if it is almost a continuous functions on any integrable set (the almost meaning, outside of a large compact set included in the specific inter garble set).